# Problem with connecting Node.js with MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am currently working on **c9 IDE** and when I run the code below, it gives me errors. How do I get around this Issue?

**app.js**

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'poream3387',
   database: 'join_us'
});

var q = 'SELECT CURTIME() as time, CURDATE as date, NOW() as now';

connection.query(q, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(results);
});

connection.end();
```

**command**:

`node app.js`

**error**:

> /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
>           throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
>           ^
>
> Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'CURDATE' in 'field list'
>       at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
>       at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:77:18)
>       at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:278:23)
>       at Parser.write (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
>       at Protocol.write (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
>       at Socket. (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)
>       at Socket. (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
>       --------------------
>       at Protocol._enqueue (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
>       at Connection.query (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:200:25)
>       at Object. (/home/ubuntu/workspace/app.js:12:12)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
>       at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)

Comment: You're missing the parenthesis in your CURDATE query. Should be `var q = 'SELECT CURTIME() as time, CURDATE() as date, NOW() as now';`

Answer (score 0):

I think, the issue is with not making **CURDATE** a function call by adding parenthesis, which is the same thing pointed out by @Jamie D